# unix read/write how to bind an asynchronous io completion function for serial port programming?

Tags: c++, c, unix, asynchronous, serial-port

For serial port programming under winapi, assining an asynchronous io completion function is easy using just **ReadFileEx**/**WriteFileEx**

What is the equivalent for unix ?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply use a separate execution thread. ReadFileEx/WriteFileEx were only needed because of historically awful performance of threads on Microsoft Windows. Although there is `SIGIO`, it's awkward. Using a separate execution thread is simpler, and more reliable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I disagree. Sometimes asynchronous operations are very beneficial.

Comment: Assuming unix == Linux (as is mostly the case here), you are looking for `aio_write`.